# Hibernate: How to map java.util.Map with java.util.Set as a value with LocalDate inside?

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping

Having an issue with mapping correctly such an object, using annotations:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "root_entity")
public RootEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    // annotations here... DayType extends Enum
    private Map<DayType, Set<LocalDate>> days;
}
```

Wanted result:

`root_entity`:

| column |
| --- |
| id |
| day_types_id |

`day_types`:

| column |
| --- |
| id |
| name |

`days_list`:

| column |
| --- |
| id |
| localdate_in_typestamp |

`day_types_to_days_list`:

| column |
| --- |
| day_type_id |
| day_list_id |

[image: To visualize]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `DayTypeEntity` which would looks something along the lines of the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "root_entity")
public RootEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "day_type_id", referencedColumnName = "day_types_id")
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "day_type_id")
    @MapKeyEnumerated(ORDINAL)
    private Map<DayType, DayTypeEntity> dayTypes;
}
@Entity
@Table(name = "day_types")
public DayTypeEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "day_type_id")
    @Enumerated(ORDINAL)
    private DayType id;

    private String name;

    @ElementCollection;
    private Set<LocalDate> days;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, had the same idea, but thought it's not enough brilliant solution for this case...